# "Incorrect syntax near 'GO'" when inserting values

Tags: c#, sql, ssms

I'm getting the error above.
I use this code:

```
  //split the script on "GO" commands
                string[] splitter = new string[] { "\r\nGO\r\n" };
                string[] commandTexts = data.Split(splitter,
                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

  foreach (string commandText in commandTexts)
  {
    SqlCommand cmdScript = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);
    cmdScript.ExecuteNonQuery();               
   }
```

I scripted the content of my tables with the SSMS so I got a file with lots of 'INSERT INTO' Statements and some 'GO' Statements between them.

The last 'GO' statement isn't at the end of the file - after the last statement there are a few 'INSERT INTO' lines. This works fine when executing it in SSMS but not in C# with the construct above.

I put a counter in to count the amount of 'commandText' int the loop. I had 3107. After I added a 'GO' at the end of the file, my counter shows 3108 and still get the error. In both cases all data gets completely inserted into my tables, so the error happens at the end.
Any idead what this could be?

Comment: what OTHER queries have you issued before the `go`? perhaps you have something like `insert ... ('foo') go`, instead of `insert .. ('foo'); go`

Comment: The syntax error is somewhere _before_ your `GO`.  The parser apparently expects something else but encounters `GO` instead.

Comment: but there are no ';' in the file. It was created by SSMS and worked fine. Could it be something going on with the split Operation above? And if it would be a char or something. Why does this happen with the counter?

Comment: manually execute commandtext in sqlserver, and see what is breaking

Comment: Well, usually they're BEGIN...END...GO if you're generating the scripts. Are you leaving those logical blocks in when you're parsing the commands?

Comment: Also, try piping the output of your splits above to a file. Examining them, you should see what's causing SQL to break.

Comment: He does not create BEGIN or END, just GO. Yes I leave it in to separate the commands at these points. I try to insert it into SSMS again

Comment: Could there be other whitespace on the Lines with GO?

Comment: I don't know. I'm trying around now if I can find the error somehow with SSMS

Comment: Ok when I'm executing it in SSMS everything is fine so I think it's something with the separator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the parser say 'syntax error before GO' it means you sent the GO to the server. It must be that your splitter does not correctly split. Is likely something like a space after the GO, making it not match the `\r\nGO\r\n` exactly.

You can give https://github.com/rusanu/DbUtilSqlCmd a try.

Comment: I'm trying. Hope this helps... although it's a very large program. Is there something smaller?

Comment: How do I run a script with the DbUtilSqlCmd? I mean... I don't know which method to call for just reading and running a script

Comment: `SqlCmd.ExecuteFile(connection, path)`

Comment: The thing of interest to you in there is the Regex used to delimit batches: `new Regex (@"^\b*GO\b*(\d*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Comment: Thank you! I managed to solve the problem on another way but this program is good too. I simply added a string with a GO statement at the end of the file (cause this was the error) and in my loop I check if this string is my current commandText - if yes -> break;

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you used a string builder instead.you could use the string builder.append class to add a new line of string

Comment: Can you give an example? Didn't use this before

Comment: Stringbuilder sb=new Stringbuilder()